# I have Python code for detecting input parameter - How to do similar in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have snippit of Python code that AUTOMATICALLY detects one of many parameters that an external program is sending.

In this case, the parameter name is date-sent

```
__name__="__main__"
import sys, os, traceback
import commands

# Switch this to 0 when in production mode.
debugMode = 1

def main(args):
    try:
        attributeMap = parseInput(args)
        dateSent = attributeMap["date-sent"]

        print "Script-attribute=script value"
        return

    except:
        error()
        print "something went wrong!"
        return "something went wrong!"

def parseInput(args):
    attributeMap = {}
    delimiter = "="
    for item in args:
        if delimiter in item:
            tuple = item.split(delimiter)
            attributeMap[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
    return attributeMap

def error():
    # "SCRIPT PROCESSING ERROR"
    if(debugMode):
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    return ""

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# DOS-style shells (for DOS, NT, OS/2):
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
def getstatusoutput(cmd):
    """ Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a
    shell."""

    pipe = os.popen(cmd + ' 2>&1', 'r')
    text = pipe.read()
    sts = pipe.close()
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    if text[-1:] == '\n': text = text[:-1]
    return sts, text

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Entry Point
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv) == 0):
        error()
    else:
        main(sys.argv)
```

How to do this in powershell, i.e. an external program that I have no control over send in many variables, i.e. sent-data, sender-name, sender-up, etc. How do I make my program detect only sent-data, just like this Python code did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$args` in Powershell, similar to `sys.argv` used in the Python example.

Read more here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730958.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this is helping me troubleshoot further.