# Python output of split function

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, split

I am trying to understand syntax of

```
attributeMap[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```

from

[I have Python code for detecting input parameter - How to do similar in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081502/i-have-python-code-for-detecting-input-parameter-how-to-do-similar-in-powershe)

It doesn't look correct because the brackets are uneven, but the program is interpreted without error. On the other hand if I change it to

```
attributeMap[tuple[0] = tuple[1]]
```

I get the error

```
File "lookup.py", line 15
attributeMap[tuple[0] = tuple[1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets are not "uneven" at all:

```
 attributeMap[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
```

We have three expressions here:

```
 tuple[0] # first element of tuple
 tuple[1] # second element of tuple
 attributeMap[tuple[0]] # value in attributeMap which has the key matching first element of tuple
```

As you can see, the third expression makes use of the first, and at the end all we do is assign the second to the third.  The brackets are in the right places.